# How get many attributes from library

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, metadata, mef

I am use [MEF][1]  and i need get from another library metadata with multiple values

Next code get dll and can get metadata, but only 1

```
public interface ISendOperationData
{
    string Organization { get; }
    string Method { get; }
}
public interface ISendOperation
{
    Task<ResponseModel> SomeMethod(RequestModel obj); 
}

public interface ISendTerminal
{
    ResponseModel GetDLL( ref RequestModel obj);
}

[Export(typeof(ISendTerminal))]
class DynamicAssemblyTerminal : ISendTerminal
{
    [ImportMany]
    IEnumerable<Lazy<ISendOperation, ISendOperationData>> operations;

    public ResponseModel GetDLL(ref RequestModel obj)
    {
        var releventDll = operations.FirstOrDefault( q => q.Metadata.Method.Contains( obj.Method ) );
    }
}

public class MefPlugin
{
    private CompositionContainer _container;

    public interface ISendOperation
    {
        Task<OperationResult<ResponseModel>> OperateAsync( RequestModel obj );
    }

    [Import( typeof( ISendTerminal ) )]
    public ISendTerminal sendCatalog;

    public MefPlugin( string extensionsPath )
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

        catalog.Catalogs.Add( new AssemblyCatalog( typeof( MefPlugin ).Assembly ) );
        catalog.Catalogs.Add( new DirectoryCatalog( extensionsPath ) );

        _container = new CompositionContainer( catalog );

        this._container.ComposeParts( this );
    }
}
```

its can get

```
[Export(typeof(ISendOperation))] 
[ExportMetadata("Organization", "Name")]
```

but i need get more than one metadata, like:

```
[Export(typeof(ISendOperation)), 
ExportMetadata("Organisation", "*"), 
ExportMetadata("Method", "one,two,fife")]
```

The problem is that I have 2 libraries that implement the same interface and I decided to change them with different attributes, which must be read somehow
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/

Comment: Are you asking "how can I read more than one attribute of the same type?" That's an _It just works_ question. As long as the attribute is defined with `AllowMuliple=true` on its `AttributeUsageAttribute` (as `ExportMetadataAttribute` does), then, when you call `GetCustomAttributes`, you'll get all the instances declared

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the point of the issue you're dealing with but:

If you declare metadata view like this:

```
public interface ISendOperationData
{
    string Organization { get; }
    string Method { get; }
}
```

Next, you specify import like this:

```
class DynamicAssemblyTerminal
{
    [ImportMany]
    IEnumerable<Lazy<ISendOperation, ISendOperationData>> operations;
}
```

Then above import of the `operations` field states that it will be filled with all `ISendOperation` exports that provide required metadata, both: `Organization` **and** `Method`.

If you have dlls that export `ISendOperation` without specifying `Method` metadata - those simply does not match the contract of the above import (and won't be used to satisfy the import).

In order to allow those exports to be also picked-up and injected during the import, declare metadata view as follows:

```
public interface ISendOperationData
{
    string Organization { get; }
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    string Method { get; }
}
```

See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/attributed-programming-model-overview-mef#metadata-and-metadata-views).